# Generating app.json for Heroku pipeline without committing it to master

Tags: heroku, github

I am investigating adding an app.json file to my heroku pipeline to enable review apps.

Heroku offers the ability to generate one from your existing app setup, but I do not see any way to prevent it from automatically committing it to our repository's master branch.

I need to be able to see it before it gets committed to the master branch because we require at least two staff members to review all changes to the master branch (which triggers an automatic staging build) for SOC-2 security compliance.

Is there a way that I can see what it would generate without committing it to the repository?

I tried forking the repo and connecting the fork to it's own pipeline, but because it did not have any of our heroku add-ons or environment, it would not work for our production pipeline.

I am hesitant to just build the app.json file manually - it seems more prone to error. I would much prefer to get the automatically generated file and selectively remove items.

Comment: How do you generate an app.json. I can't find documentation to do that anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

As a punchline to this story, I ended up investing enough time into the forked repository on it's own pipeline to demonstrate a POC

Answer (score -1):

When you generate your `app.json` file, it should take you to a secondary screen that has the full `app.json` in plaintext at the bottom.

Why not open a PR with its contents in your project root. Once it's detected on the repository Heroku shouldn't ask you to regenerate it again.